What do hormones like adrenaline and testosterone look like?
I am getting into character design, and I am trying to design a character that is a manifestation of violence. I got to thinking: hormones influence behavior, and unless I am wrong, the leading hormones that trigger aggression are adrenaline and testosterone. So maybe a character that has a body made up of adrenaline or testosterone would fit greatly!
The only issue is that I don't know what those hormones look like, or any hormones for that matter.
So if you were to somehow get yourself a vial of pure adrenaline or testosterone, what would they physically look like to your eyes?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/adrenaline https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone … quite boring molecules.

@Martin-マーチン, OP wants physical appearance to the human eye, not (admittedly boring steroid) structure. (Cubane might be more photogenic ;-)

@Martin-マーチン Uhm, surprisingly simple perhaps? Boring, never. Quite interesting how organisms assemble to use precise molecular structures. Change them slightly and the results can be everything but boring.

Most compounds, organic in particular, are just white powders / clear liquids... and living being can hardly be made from just one.

@Buck There are no uninteresting molecules: If there were uninteresting molecules, there would be a smallest uninteresting molecule. This would be a very interesting property. Therefore: there are no uninteresting molecules. :P


So if you were to somehow get yourself a vial of pure adrenaline or testosterone, what would they physically look like to your eyes?

Both adrenaline (AKA epinephrine) and testosterone look like water, in the usual dissolved form as administered, or as crystals, similar to crystals of acetylsalicylic acid  grown from aspirin tablets, below:

from https://wikimedia.org
However, crystals of adrenaline and testosterone (and also aspirin), viewed through crossed polarizers, are brightly colored due to birefringence. For that matter, even cellophane tape ("Scotch Tape") is birefringent.

from https://images.fineartamerica.com
For strictly personal artistic purposes, you might find the second image meaningful to you in your dramatic production. That said, there is nothing to distinguish that pretty picture of adrenaline from a picture of aspirin, viewed the same way. Someone looking at that image would not know it is adrenaline.

Maybe the  character exudes adrenaline in vapor form and gets everyone nearby excited. And maybe they wear a costume made of lenses that makes the birefringent property evident and confuses enemies. The sidekick dishes out aspirins after the bad guys get their asses kicked.

@BuckThorn, that would be too much of a headache. And they ain't bad guys, just misunderstood.
